# How to make same button to increase count and revert back to its previous state in React (useState)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the count by one and make the same button revert back to its previous state on click.

Comment: you mean change to 1 and back to 0 again

Comment: Can you share some of the code you wrote?

Comment: So you click the button and state increases from 0 to 1. And then you click it again and it goes back to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const CountButton = () => {
  previousState = 100;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(false);
  return(
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => setCount(!count)}>Click Me!</button>
     <div>{count ? previousState + 1 : previousState }</div>
   </div>
  )
}
```

This code will increase the vote by one and then revert on the second click.